# why apache force me to use https?

Tags: apache, virtualhost

i have a problem with apache2 on localhost
i have many virtualhost and thats worked fine before, but today i have a problem
when i try open test-bot.app apache force me to https://test-web.app!
this is my vhost file:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
        ServerName test-bot.app
        ServerAlias test-bot.app
        DocumentRoot /var/www/html/test-bot/public
        <Directory />
            AllowOverride All
        </Directory>
        <Directory /var/www/html/test-bot/public>
            Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
            AllowOverride all
            Require all granted
        </Directory>
        ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/test-bot.app-error.log
        LogLevel error
        CustomLog /var/log/apache2/test-bot.app-access.log combined
    </VirtualHost>
```

what can i do?

Comment: Could it be that it's not Apache but your application?

Comment: i fond solution, it's not apache, firefox redirect any .app tld to https